# vb.net Splitting string lines into new strings

Tags: vb.net, string, arraylist, split

I want to split a string - which includes multiple lines - into new strings.

As it seems that people dont understand my problem here some further informations:

I read out values into strings from a XML-file. Some of those strings countain multiple lines. Now I need every single value of that string on a new string(variable) so that I can tell Homer to drink a beer and tell Lenny to go to bed and not tell the whole Team to go to bed. (Hopefully this story helps you :D )

To keep this simple I'll define a "static" string for this sample.

I'll put 3 of my tries down below. I'd love to hear what's wrong with them. I also tried it with `lists` and `enums` where I could split the string but no define a new one.. 
But I assume that there is a much easier solution for my problem...

```
Dim team As String = "Simpson, Homer" & vbCrLf & "Leonard, Lenny" & vbCrLf & "Carlson, Carl"
```

1.

```
        Dim objReader As New StringReader(team)
        Dim tm() As String
        Dim i As Integer = 1

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            tm(i) = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop
```

2. ```
       Dim i As Integer = 0

       For Each Line As String In team.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbTab)})
           Dim tm(i) As String = ReadLine(team, i)
           i = i + 1
       Next
   ```

   3.

   ```
   Dim tm() As String
   Dim i As Integer = 0
   Dim objReader As New StringReader(team)

   Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
       tm(i) = ReadLine(team, i)
       i = i + 1
   Loop
   ```

And the function used in 2. and 3.

```
    Public Function ReadLine(ByVal sFile As String, Optional ByVal nLine As Long = 1) As String

    Dim sLines() As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFile As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
        oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile)
        sLines = Split(oFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
        oFile.Close()

        Select Case Math.Sign(nLine)
            Case 1
                ReadLine = sLines(nLine - 1)
            Case -1
                ReadLine = sLines(UBound(sLines) + nLine + 1)
        End Select
    End If

    ErrHandler:
    oFile = Nothing
    oFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Thanks in advance for any shared thoughts.

Comment: Are you just looking for a code review? What "doesn't work"? Why is the `Split()` string extension method not sufficient?

Comment: What is the exact question? Do you get any errors while executin your code? Do the expected and actual behavior match? 
One hint for function `ReadLine`: Currently you are opening and reading the file in a loop. I would change it to only read the content of the text file once and store it in a string collection split by new line or at least declare the file reader object only once.

Comment: @slugster All my tries dont work atm as my VB Express 10 underlines the `tm(i)` as it askes for a value, but if I define a value, it wouldnt be dynamic anymore.

Comment: @AlexB. Try 1 and 3 stop running at `tm(i) =` with the message "No objectreference defined" and Try 2 wont run at all as also `tm(i)` is underlined with the message "no explicit initialisation allowed"
Thanks for the hint on the function :) I'll see what I can do :D

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you're never declaring the size of your array, or redim-ing it as necessary when you add a new string.

Comment: If it's a file, you might want to take a look at the [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) method. If it's a string, just use split. Is "team" a list of filenames? What is the content of the files? You might also want to look at List(Of String).

Comment: @Capellan is it possible to declare the Array size as endless? or should I first count how many lines there are in the string and then set the size or the array?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  ReDim would let you increase the array size dynamically (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx).  My personal preference would be to use a List(Of String) like @the_lotus suggested (or string collection like Alex said), that way you can just keep using the Add method of the collection.

Comment: No it is not possible to delcare an Array with infinite bounds. Please try what @the_lostus suggested: Use ReadAllLines and store the result in a Generic.List(Of String). A list can be looped e.g. via For Each or queried with LINQ.

Comment: @the_lotus It's a string. The value in the sample string I use here is equal to the ones I have in my script. It just has to be dynamic, as the number of teammembers might change - that's why I can't take `team(3)`

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(sFile)` will do exactly what you want. It returns an string array spilt by the lines out of file `sFile`.

Comment: probably I dont get it but, `File.ReadAlLines` askes for a source file and I have my values in a string. Or if you want me to use it on my source file, which is a XML, it wouldnt work either as it askes for a .txt-file

Comment: Wait..what do you mean with source file? Out of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array, and then closes the file." And according to your current code you want to read strings from a physical file stored on a HDD or similar. Otherwise your function `ReadLine` is completely useless for your needs.

Comment: @AlexB. as I already said, probably I understand something wrong. But, just try these short lines:
`Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Dim team As String = "Simpson, Homer" & vbCrLf & "Leonard, Lenny" & vbCrLf & "Carlson, Carl"

    Sub Main()

        File.ReadAllLines(team)

    End Sub

End Module`

Comment: Ok so just another case of misconception. Is my summary correct: You want to split a given string variable by new lines into a collection of just these strings in order to access them dynamically later on?

Comment: @AlexB. sorry for the bad formating.. ohh.. I see your point. sorry my fault (funny though it still works) I used this function earlier where I wasn't able of reading out XML-file - therefor I used .txt-files back then

Comment: @AlexB. okey I try to explain it. I read out values into strings from a XML-file. Some of those strings countain multiple lines. Now I need every single value of that string on a new string(variable) so that I can tell Homer to drink a beer and tell Lenny to go to bed and not tell the whole Team to go to bed. (Hopefully this story helps you :D )

Comment: Since this is a complete new request please update your original answer with the new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact an easy solution for my problem. Sorry if I caused confusion.

```
Module Module1
    Dim team As String = "Simpson, Homer" & vbCrLf & "Leonard, Lenny" & vbCrLf & "Carlson, Carl"

    Sub Main()
        Dim tm As String() = team.Split(vbLf)

        'Test
        Console.WriteLine(tm(0)) 'Homer
        Console.WriteLine(tm(1)) 'Lenny
        Console.WriteLine(tm(2)) 'Carl
    End Sub

End Module
```